# Magnifier.js Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magnifier

Magento 2.3.3 and Magnifier not working correctly.

This is what you see on my website
[image]

```
<var name="magnifier">
     <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
     <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
     <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
     <var name="width">400</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
     <var name="height">400</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
     <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
     <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

In https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25027 add proprierties

**max-height:inherit;**

**object-fit: cover;**

```
.magnifier-preview img {
    left: 0;
    max-width: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

But zoom position not working

Comment: Please add right 
 image width and height

Comment: Whats the original dimension of this image? Upload a different image for testing.

Comment: small: 649x649 , big: 2100x2100
I tested with a different image, but not changed anything